# how to make svn or git only monitor a list of files, but ignores anything else

Tags: git, svn, version-control, gitignore, svnignore

for example there are lots of files in one directory, but i only want to monitor Makefile and rules.mk ... , what i should input to .gitignore or .svnignore?

```
ls
bin        Config.in  docs                include  **Makefile**  Packages     README.SDK  scripts      target
build_dir  dl         feeds.conf.default  LICENSE  package   Packages.gz  **rules.mk**    staging_dir  tmp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for a `.gitignore` file would ignore everything and then exclude `Makefile` and `rules.mk`

```
>>.gitignore cat
*
!Makefile
!rules.mk
```

Note that you could just ignore everything after you have added `Makefile` and `rules.mk` and you wouldn't notice a difference.